# @Input property is undefined in Angular 2's onInit

Tags: angular

Trying to get the component's `@Input` value in `constructor` or `ngOnInit`. But it is coming as `undefined` all the time.

I updated the hero plunker with `console.log` to show the issue (beta angular).
http://plnkr.co/edit/dseNM7OTFi1VNG2Z4Oj5?p=preview

```
export class HeroDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(){
    console.log('hero', this.hero)
  }
  public hero: Hero;
  
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('hero', this.hero)
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Hmm, I didn't realize that in the example we are not selecting immidatelly the Hero... I was happy that it is not working in the plunker either :) I checked it in plunker and it is working fine. However in my code it is not working but it is initialized...  sorry for the wrong plunker. I will accept the answer however  it doesnt solve my issue.

Comment: So the problem was that I have put camelCase property "inputProperty" in the @Input... instead of "input-property" ... strange didnt realize.. however in the API documentation is written like this.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

The reason you're getting undefined in `ngOnInit` is because at the point where the component is initialised you haven't actually passed in a `Hero` object

```
<my-hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero"></my-hero-detail>
```

At this point `selectedHero` has no value in your `AppComponent` and doesn't until the click event on the list calls the `onSelect` method

**Edit:** Sorry realised I didn't actually offer a fix. If you add an `ngIf` to `my-hero-detail`

```
<my-hero-detail *ngIf="selectedHero" [hero]="selectedHero"></my-hero-detail>
```

you should this will delay the initialisation of the `my-hero-detail` component and you should see the console output. This *wont* however output again when the selected hero changes.

Answer (score 49):

This is because the heroes are loaded asynchronously, so when the view renders initially, the selected hero is undefined. But then after a selection is made, the hero is passed into the details view with a defined value.

You are basically just seeing the onInit call based on the original value (undefined).

If you want something similar to execute after each selection, you can modify it like this:

```
export class HeroDetailComponent implements AfterViewChecked {
  constructor(){
    console.log('hero', this.hero)
  }
  public hero: Hero;

  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    console.log('hero', this.hero)
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it should.

Comment: using angular5 . Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined'. Current value: '[object Object]'.

Comment: @FaizMohamedHaneef that happens if you change a value in that function. Since angular has already checked all the variables for changes it gives you a warning if you change a value afterwards in debug mode (not in production, since angular doesn't check again like in debug). If you really need to change a value and you are sure you are handling it correctly, wrap it in a Timeout.

Answer (score 27):

I encountered the same behavior when I've got undefined of Input property value in `ngOnInit`. The statement `*ngIf="selectedHero"` in html code was not satisfied me. Moreover, using `AfterViewChecked` from [@THG's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34396984/2674033) was not a good solution for me, because it calls periodically and also it causes the warning `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` when I want to change some variable (I didn't want to use workaround `setTimeout`). This is my solution for kind of this issue:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnChanges {
    @Input() myVariable: any;

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        if (changes['myVariable']) {
            let variableChange = changes['myVariable'];
            //do something with variableChange.currentValue
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it helps someone later.

Comment: The if statement and bracketed variable did not work in my case, instead I simply checked for another condition. But it worked!!

Thank you

Comment: it's working properly. I don't know why hasn't he approved this.

Comment: This is right way to do. We have to use "ngOnChanges()" when an input/output binding value changes, so to catch incoming value from @Input binding use above method. Although params provided in above example are because ngOnChanges() method receives a SimpleChanges object of current and previous property values to utilize further.

Answer (score 0):

In the ngOninit method use,

```
ngOnInit() {
    if(this.hero) 
        console.log('hero', this.hero);
}
```

Comment: Can someone explain why this was downvoted? It got rid of this error in my unit test.

Comment: The question was to not to skip the error but find a way to fix the error

Answer (score 0):

@Barabas solution did not work in my case. I end up using this

```
export class HeroDetailComponent implements OnChanges {
    @Input() hero: any;

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
        if(changes.hero && changes.hero.currentValue){
            let currentHero = changes.hero.currentValue;
            //use currentHero
        }
    }
}
```