# Angular 2: Do something with @Input inside Component

Tags: angular

How can I do something with the @Input value inside the component??

For example:

```
<log-user [user]="user"></log-user>
```

Let's assume that `user` is an object. Now, I know how I can pass this user data inside te log-user template, but how can I do something with this `user` inside its component??

`LogUserComponent`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'log-user',
  template: `

    This works: {{user}}

  `
})

export class LogUserComponent {

  @Input() user:any;

  constructor() {
    // this get's logged as undefined??
    console.log(this.user);
  }
}
```

Any help would be great!! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

On construction time the `@Input` value is not yet set. How could Angular2 set the `@Input` value before the component was actually constructed?

You have to wait for the component to be initialized; meaning all `@Input` values have been set. You can do so by implementing the `OnInit` interface.

So to fix your example:

```
<log-user [user]="user"></log-user>
```

<sup>*(Note: `user` must be a defined object, otherwise in this example undefined would still be logged. You can add `*ngIf="user"` to the `log-user` html tag to ensure the tag does not get rendered before `user` actually exists.)*</sup>

Do:

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'log-user',
  template: `This works: {{user}}`
})
export class LogUserComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() user:any;

  ngOnInit() {
    // this now gets logged as 'user'
    console.log(this.user);
  }
}
```

You can also just create the `ngOnInit` method on your component without implementing the interface, but by importing the `OnInit` interface you are ensured by the Typescript compiler not make a typo mistake.

The [Angular docs about OnInit](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit) states:

> Implement this interface to execute custom initialization logic after
>   your directive's data-bound properties have been initialized.
>
> ngOnInit is called right after the directive's data-bound properties
>   have been checked for the first time, and before any of its children
>   have been checked. It is invoked only once when the directive is
>   instantiated.

Comment: Thanks for your time, but I already tried that, and it still logs as undefined?

Comment: Also, instead of passing an object, I tried passing just a string: `<log-user [user]="'just a string'"></log-user>`. This works and gets logged inside the component. So is there something wrong by passing in an object the way I tried? @Lodewijk

Comment: Nope nothing wrong with that. It just must exist before the controller is instantiated.

Comment: I've added a note to address this.

Comment: This approach isn't working. I did exactly as shown in the example.

Answer (score 7):

After some more research, I found this post "[@Input property is undefined in angular 2's onInit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34396684/input-property-is-undefined-in-angular-2s-oninit)".

So the answer is actually quite easy. Because in this example the `user` is an object coming from an API call, it is undefined at initialization of the component (hope I'm saying this the right way).. Using `*ngIf` fixes this:

`<log-user *ngIf="user" [user]="user"></log-user>`

Comment: Good point. I've added a note to my answer that addresses this point, so that people who have the same kind of question can get the entire answer in one go. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Since our Angular components are ES6 classes with a @Component() decorator we’re able to leverage TS accessors to intercept the injected value as follows:

The main difference is that instead of decorating the property we decorate the setter.

More details http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

```
<log-user [user]="user"></log-user>
```

Inside Component.ts

```
export class LogUserComponent {
  private _user:any;

  get user() {
    return this._user;
  }
  @Input() 
  set user( user:any) {
    // to catch undefined user 
    if(!user) return;
    this._user = user;
    // modify the user here example below
    // this._user = 'X' + user;
  }

  constructor() {

  }
}
```