# Angular2 input and highcharts

Tags: angular

I'm using [angular2-highcharts](https://github.com/gevgeny/angular2-highcharts) to create a pie chart and I use an input to pass the data to the chart. But the input is `undefined` on the component constructor and the chart is not displayed.
I'm already using `*ngIf` and in fact the div hides if I set the input to `undefined` and shows when I pass some data. However the chart still does not show.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'pie-chart',
    directives: [CHART_DIRECTIVES],
    template: `
        <chart [options]="options"></chart>
    `
})
export class PieChartComponent {
    options: HighchartsOptions;
    @Input() pieChartData : Array<{name: string, y: number}>

    constructor () {        
        this.setChartOptions();        
    }    

    setChartOptions() {
        console.log("creating pie "+ this.pieChartData) <- undefined

        this.options = {
            ...,
            series: [{
                data: this.pieChartData
            }]
        };
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<div *ngIf="pieChartData" >
      <pie-chart [pieChartData]="pieChartData"></pie-chart>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How did you get the pie charts working in angular2-highcharts?  Can you share an example?

Comment: @MichaelJDI I've created a plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/lNYIh0kUdp63WSXxkuti

Comment: Thanks for the Plunkr! Helped me get an angular2-highchart piechart in my app

Answer (score 0):

Implementing OnInit solved my problem as stated [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34568344/6414258).

```
export class PieChartComponent implements OnInit {
    options: HighchartsOptions;
    @Input() pieChartData : Array<{name: string, y: number}>

    ngOnInit () {        
        this.setChartOptions();        
    }    
...
}
```