# Getting undefined inside ngOnInit when accessing array within object

Tags: angular

I have two console logs inside a ngOnInit. When, I look in the console the object shows but when I try accessing Depts (An array within the object) it shows undefined.[image][image]
[image]

Comment: Make a constructor constructor () { this.columns = this.products.Depts; } and then your console.log should work as planned. Similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34396684/input-property-is-undefined-in-angular-2s-oninit

Comment: I am getting (added your suggestion):  TypeError: Cannot read property 'Depts' of undefined

Comment: Are you importing the `Dept` class into both your components (parent and child)?

Comment: I only imported it in ProductGridComponent

Comment: What does your console.log(this.products.Depts) produce? If nothing, what about console.log(this.products[0].Depts)?

Comment: If it's not the async nature, it's likely you're just calling the object correctly and you need to get that straight.

Comment: I added the constructor(){console.log(this.products)} and I get undefined. I also tried ngAfterViewChecked(){console.log(this.products)} and this gave an undefined as well.

Comment: What you seem to be getting is an array, so it should be `this.products[0].Depts`... just like Z Bagley pointed out.

Comment: Thank you both for the help. Right, now I am getting undefined when I just use this.products. If, I can get an array to display in the console then I will try this.products[0].Depts. The console view in the post shows the structure of the object.

Comment: Where is this console log then from, I thought it was from the oninit? And in the console log it's not an object, it's an array :)

Comment: Okay, I see what you guys were saying. I reverted back to ngOnInit and added this.products[0].Depts and it worked. Thank you both for the help and guidance.