# Angular get @input data not printed on template

Tags: angular

I want @input data in Oninit. Input data is not printed in the template but it gets printed in the console log.

```
// foo-child.ts
@Input('tableData')
set tableData(tableData) {
  if (tableData) {
    this.tableDataReceived = this.tableDataShow = tableData;
    this.totalRows = this.tableDataShow.length;
  }
}

// foo-child.html
<div class="block">
  <div class="block50 selected-text"><span *ngIf="selectedRow">{{selectedRow.length}}</span><span *ngIf="!selectedRow">0</span> Requisition Selected</div>
  <div class="block50 result-no">10 of <span *ngIf="tableData">{{totalRows}}</span> Results</div>
</div>

// foo-parent.html
<foo-child *ngIf="tableData" [tableData]="tableData"></foo-child>
```

Comment: can you show more of the component thats passing the data object?

Comment: Please check if updated code is Ok

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34396684/input-property-is-undefined-in-angular-2s-oninit

Comment: the .ts file that holds the data and pass it down, it might be that when you pass it initially its undefined, try and giving that data on the parent component a default value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [@Input property is undefined in angular 2's onInit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34396684/input-property-is-undefined-in-angular-2s-oninit)

Comment: You use `tableData` and `selectedRow` variables in your child template. Where are those variables defined in the child component? My guess is that they are always null.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using setter for input then `*ngIf="tableData"` never evaluates to `true`. To make it work stop using a setter or change the condition to: `*ngIf="totalRows"`.