# Use @Input in ngOnInit

Tags: angular

I have passed the app `object` from parent component to child component using `@Input`. Now I am trying to use that on `ngOnInit` of the child component. The object is only available on `ngOnChanges`, so could not use on `ngOnInit`. Still I tried something like below but cannot make it work.

**Component**

```js
@Input() app;
appModified;

listDetails() {
    this.appService.getDetails(this.appModified);
}

ngOnChanges() {
    console.log(this.app)
    this.appModified = this.app;
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.listDetails();
}
```

listDetails is `undefined`.

I tried [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34396684/input-property-is-undefined-in-angular-2s-oninit) but still couldn't fix it.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: call `this.listDetails();` in **`ngAfterViewInit()`**

Comment: @Faisal i tried it as well but didn't work

Comment: ngOnInit() {
 setTimeout(()=>{
  this.listDetails();
 },0)
}

Comment: You do know that ngOnChanges can be called more then once right?

Comment: if you check your input data in parent component then it will fill the data when it's full, ```<child *ngIf="objects" [app]="objects"></child>``` whats the problem with this?

Comment: check [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zsnkro).

Answer (score -2):

@surazzarus

make sure that your html template is similar like below, where `someString` content binds the instance to the child's `name` property:

```
<hello [name]="someString"></hello>
```

`someString` variable was declared in my app.component like this way:

```
someString: string = '123 123 123';
```

And the finish piece of code:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<span>{{name}}</span>`
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() name: string;
  
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.name);
}

  ngOnChanges() {
    console.log(this.name)
}
}
```

hope it would help you

check the whole sample [here](http://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-inputs-sample)