# Edit variable passed into an Angular 8 Web component

Tags: angular, angular8, web-component

I have created a web component (let's name it test component) with Angular 8 that receives an input and shows it to the browser (`test.component.html` file)

```
<h3>{{title}}</h3>
```

The `test.component.ts` file receives the input and also logs it in the console

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  @input() title;

  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit() {console.log(this.title)}
}
```

The `index.html` of a standalone application that uses the web component looks like this:

```
<test-component title="this is a string"></test-component>
```

It correctly displays the string and logs it to the console.

The problem arises when I use the web component inside an existing angular application. The variable I want to pass to the web component is dynamic and comes from the existing application's component. I have tried passing it inside a component that already exists (for example `existing-application.component.html`) in two different ways:

```
<test-component [title]="titleVariable"></test-component>

<test-component title={{titleVariable}}></test-component>
```

where the titleVariable is defined in the associated `existing-application.component.html` file like this

```
export class ExistingApplicationComponent implements OnInit {

  titleVariable= 'this is a string';

  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Here, while the h1 html element correctly displays the string the console.log is undefined.

I have also tried logging it (in the web component) in the ngAfterViewInit() instead of the ngOnInit() without any luck.

Does anyone have an idea on why this could be happening?
Thanks in advance for your time

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34396684/input-property-is-undefined-in-angular-2s-oninit

Comment: Thanks a lot @Layera though it does not answer my question directly it surely does give me something else to try.

Comment: Has the value of the `titleVariable` changed in your tries, or was it fix?

Comment: The value of titleVariable is fixed but I need to parse and edit it before showing it to the h1, I tried using the ngAfterViewChecked() lifecycle but it runs multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with life-cycle hooks. You need `ngOnChanges()` life-cylce hook when you want to access the `input()` properties.

NgOnChanges: "Respond when Angular (re)sets data-bound input properties. The method receives a SimpleChanges object of current and previous property values.
Called before ngOnInit() and whenever one or more data-bound input properties change.
"

Comment: But if you want to change the property value, you can use a `pipe`. https://angular.io/guide/pipes

Comment: The ngOnChanges() lifecycle works but the logging is done twice, first time with undefined and the second time it gets logged correctly.

Comment: Because the `ngOnChanges()` run multiple times, before `ngOnInit()` and after `input()` re-sets. If you want to access this property and modifie, use `pipe`s in HTML template.

Comment: Pipe is a really good idea but because I am building a web component, I need it to work in standalone applications as well. For example having the custom element inside an empty index.html file without angular could not work with pipe.

Comment: Oh, then you can check in the `ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges)` function the `input` value, in the `changes` object whit an if satement, and there you can change the value like this: `export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() name: string;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes && changes.name) {
      this.name = 'Excepted value';
    }
  }
}`