# issue with angular specially how to send data from component parent to component child

Tags: angular

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-parent',
   templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})
  export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
    variableParent:string='je viens du parent'
    constructor() { }

      ngOnInit(): void {
      }

}
<p>parent works!</p>
<app-enfant [ValueChild]="variableParent" ></app-enfant>

//**********child component*****
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-enfant',
  templateUrl: './enfant.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./enfant.component.css']
})
export class EnfantComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input () ValueChild:any
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
   console.log(this.ValueChild)
  }

}

<p>enfant works!</p>
  <h3>
   {{ValueChild}}
  </h3>
```

//Unfortunately {{ValueChild}} is undefined I don't know why normally ValueChild
//should display: "je viens du parent" in the browser
please could you help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You app-infant is getting created before the property is being passed.

So you wouldn't see its value on ngonInit

See: [@Input property is undefined in Angular 2's onInit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34396684/input-property-is-undefined-in-angular-2s-oninit)

Comment: sorry but, your proposal does not work for me!